# indoor positioning system: which is better?

Tags: slam

Which method is better, in term of accuracy, for detection of indoor localization of a drone. Camera based system or wireless techniques like WLAN or Bluetooth?

Comment: I voted to close this because it is primarily opinion based. If you have some specifications you can provide this might be a good question (cost, range, accuracy, lighting conditions, number of sensors, etc.), but as it stands a "which is better A or B" with no qualifiers can't be answered.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be reworded to highlight the strength/weakness trade-offs between the different sensing schemes, rather than which one is *better*.

Comment: Sadly @Ben *list questions* tend not to be very useful for very long either. While they may provide a nice snapshot at a moment in time, they are frequently left to get out of date. That's why we prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Ameer Hamza, but I'm afraid that questions like this are not a good fit for a stack exchange question. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it is a good idea to include details of what what you would like to achieve, what you have tried, what you expected to see and what you actually saw. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. If you edit your question to make it less opinion based, flag it and we can reopen it for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Definitely camera based options, however, I would go with IR sensors or some even some sound-based sensors if you want a really specific measurement.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, wireless signals are quite less acurate than camera based ones. Probably the best would be IR sensors equipment with cameras, but that's also the most expensive